# Elevation not working for BottomSheet inside Coordinator layout

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout, elevation, bottom-sheet

I am trying to use a `BottomSheet` in my layout.
The root view is an `CoordinatorLayout` and I want to set `Elevation` on top for the Bottom Sheet so i am setting it with a high value (50dp), however it is not showing when the app runs but it appears on android studio design tool.

I have tried to set background for the sheet with a solid color instead of gradient but it still did work. I also tried to use Shadow shapes but it does not give the same elevation appearance.

here is my XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.atefhares.StartActivity"
    android:clipToPadding="false">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/DetailsView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Details Should be shown here"
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:textSize="25sp"
                android:padding="20dp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:context="com.atefhares.Start_Activity" />


    </LinearLayout>
    <android.support.v4.widget.SlidingPaneLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:behavior_peekHeight="70dp"
        app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior"
        android:background="@drawable/gradiant"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:elevation="50dp">


        <include layout="@layout/bottom_sheet_layout"/>

    </android.support.v4.widget.SlidingPaneLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Edit:
bottom_sheet_layout.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/inviteLL">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:background="@drawable/invite_icon"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Invite Friends"
            android:textSize="22sp"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:id="@+id/inviteTV"

            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:id="@+id/arrowIV"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:background="@drawable/arrow_up" />
    </LinearLayout>


    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/usersLV"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:divider="#ffffff"
        android:background="#ffffff" />

</LinearLayout>
```

So **how can I make the elevation shows on top of the `Bottom Sheet`**

Any one can help, please ?

Comment: Same issue here :) upvoted your question. May I suggest you to add a screenshot? Also added a bounty

Comment: what android version phone did you use to test?

Comment: Post your bottom sheet layout code

Comment: @piotrek1543 versions M , K , L

Comment: @BurhanuddinRashid, check

Comment: change your parent layout from LinearLayout to FrameLayout or similar supporting elevation

Comment: @DanieleSegato, yes sure, add your suggestion and I will approve it if it is the same

Comment: @piotrek1543 didn't work and i wasn't expect it to work!

Comment: @piotrek1543 even a CardView doesn't show with elevation on this. Atef i was suggesting you add your screenshot :)

Comment: @DanieleSegato I have added my answer, hope it can help you and Atef.

Comment: I solved the issue in my own Layout. I just had a `clipToPadding="true"` that was pointless there. I failed to see it apparently. Have you tried wrapping the SlidePaneLayout into another view and give to THAT view the BottomSheetBehavior? Also is by any chance your view transparent? By default views use the background to define the Outline: no background = no outline = no shadow. Check this: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewOutlineProvider.html

Comment: @DanieleSegato, Yes I tried to use `Linear layout` instead of  `SlidingPaneLayout` => no difference, and I changed the background to solid color => no difference

Comment: more like try to remove the background

Comment: @AtefHares I found other guys having the same issue: http://stackoverflow.com/q/32395983/2013835 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/27741567/2013835

Comment: @JJ86 Yes I saw these questions but the answers are all about using workarounds :(

Comment: @AtefHares I never saw an elevation on top of a view on app (Google apps and other). As I suggested in my answer, maybe is not possible. Of course If it exists, I will be the first to implement it ;-) .

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SlidingPaneLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet"
xmlns:slide_panel="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:behavior_peekHeight="70dp"
      app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior"
        android:background="@drawable/gradiant"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        slide_panel:elevation="50dp">
```

Comment: elevation is only working for greater than 5.0 devices

Comment: Elevation works everywhere on 5+ devices. It's a View attribute. But here it doesn't work because of something the BottomSheetBehavior does, the modification you suggest: using slide_panel:elevation in place of android:elevation is pointless.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [google guidelines](https://material.google.com/material-design/environment.html#environment-light-shadow) with the android:elevation is not possible (Also you can read more about the [keyligth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-point_lighting)).

Anyway on the most common cases when you scroll up the "BottomSheet" a semitransparent layer appears behind the "BottomSheet", this helps to keep the user focus on the "BottomSheet" actions, like [these examples](https://material.google.com/components/bottom-sheets.html#bottom-sheets-modal-bottom-sheets).

If anyway you want a top shadow you can set a drawable background with gradient like this (shadow_top.xml):

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
<gradient
    android:angle="90"
    android:centerColor="#000000"
    android:endColor="@android:color/transparent"
    android:startColor="#000000"
    android:type="linear" />
```

And your SlidingPanelLayout will be:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SlidingPaneLayout
    android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:behavior_peekHeight="95dp"
    android:paddingTop="25dp"
    app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior"
    android:background="@drawable/shadow_top"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    >
```

Best regards.

Comment: no where in the google guidelines it say it is not possible

Comment: On the guidelines says "Combined shadow from key and ambient lights" and you can see how the lights are pointing.

Comment: yep. It doesn't say no shadow below. It's combined. And ambient light has no direction.

Comment: true, but look at "Shadow cast by key light", there is no shadow on the top, you can assume the direction of the key light (I didn't see an option to change the key light on android) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_light

Comment: i've a bottomsheetlayout in my app it has elevation and i can SEE the elevation on top. It's LOT less visible then how it would be if bottom (16dp) but It is visible. So your argument is invalid. The ambient shadow is visible top.

Comment: Again.. I said "look at "SHADOW CAST BY KEY LIGHT", there is no shadow on the top" I know that shadow on the top it's the result of ambient light, most part of the final shadow is caused by the "Shadow cast by key light" and until I know, on android, you can't change/reverse this light.

Answer (score 0):

Do not forget that to draw shadow you must use hardwareAccelerated drawing

hardwareAccelerated = true  [image]

hardwareAccelerated = false [image]

See [Android Hardware Acceleration](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html) for details

Comment: it is enabled by default

Answer (score 0):

The answer is: *no, it is not possible* (unless you create your own view custom with an elevation feature on top).

**Elevetion** is not meant to be visible in the top of a view, but in the bottom, on the right and on the left.

If you see closely on the [official Material Design](https://material.google.com/components/bottom-navigation.html#) guidelines, you can see that the bottom bar simply don't have it (do not confuse with the gray space between the card and the bottom bar).

[image]

For example: import **Card View** sample from Android Studio and play with it with emulator or your device. You will see that if you increment the elevation value, the view will have his shadow everywhere except on top (see second image below).

[image]

Another example is given by importing **Elevation Basic**.

**EDIT**

Following code is taken from **Card View** sample. There is a layout containing a `CardView` with *elevation*. Whenever you change the elevation, you will always see shadow everywhere, but not on top (the code was tested with Lollipop and Marshmallow).

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
              android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
              android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
              android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    >
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cardview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:elevation="100dp"
        card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@color/cardview_initial_background"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_large"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_large"
        >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin_medium"
            android:text="@string/cardview_contents"
            />
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_large"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        >
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="@dimen/seekbar_label_length"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="@string/cardview_radius_seekbar_text"
            />
        <SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/cardview_radius_seekbar"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin_medium"
            />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        >
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="@dimen/seekbar_label_length"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="@string/cardview_elevation_seekbar_text"
            />
        <SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/cardview_elevation_seekbar"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin_medium"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I appreciate the detailed response but this is simply not true. As you can see from the image here: https://developer.android.com/training/material/shadows-clipping.html a shadow can be clearly see on top of the view. The reason your image is showing no shadow on top is surely something else (some clipping in your layout for example).

Comment: @DanieleSegato thank you, but I clearly see the swadow on left, right and on bottom of the first rectangle. The example is taken from Google code, I have updated my answer.

Comment: @DanieleSegato this dude added more details, including a link to another guidelines: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39380091/2013835 .

Comment: I've my code right here with shadow on top using elevation. Working. For me. The issue was very stupid. For the original question it's something else. But the answer is NOT: "impossible to have shadow on top".

Comment: @DanieleSegato good, can you share the code in another answer, or maybe edit mine?

Comment: my code is a lot different from the one of the question. And the problem with it was a clipToPadding attribute that I totally failed to notice when I added the bounty to this question. I've no time now to investigate its code but I would guess it's something related to the background of the view

Comment: This answer is absolutely misleading. There IS shadow on top of the view with elevation. You can see the cuts in your example on every side of the card, not only on top, so it is an issue with your layout, not with the shadow on top. As a key to understand try to play with `clipToPadding` attribute.

Comment: Thank you for your comments, will try out to improve that.