# Card View shadow much thicker at the bottom than at the top

Tags: android, android-cardview, cardview

I have an app that uses CardViews very extensively, pretty much for every UI element in each view. I noticed that the shadow around each CardView is much thicker around views close to the bottom than it is around views closer to the top:

[image: example]

Any idea why that is, and if there's a way to change that behavior?

Comment: and what is wrong?

Comment: shadow always works this way

Answer (score 2):

That is so because that is what Material Design was mean to represent.

CardView appears to be thick at the bottom as that represents the shadow which a real card will cast if the cardView was replaced by it.

If you want to tweak this parameter, you'll need to adjust the  `android:elevation="2dp"` attribute for the cardView.

Setting it to `0dp` will disable the shadow and increasing it will increase it.

If you want to have shadows all around the cardView, refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36779481/5471095) which explains how to achieve it.

Comment: Thanks, sorry, I didn't word my question correctly. More info in my response to Sergey, but as you say I don't think what I want is doable using card view elevation.

Comment: @NirArbel you can view this answer to display an even shadow across your card view. 
http://stackoverflow.com/a/36779481/5471095

Comment: @the-dagger he's saying cardviews displayed lower on the screen have thicker shadows than those at the top of the screen. i'm seeing this behavior as well.

Answer (score 0):

It's a normal behavior of `android:elevation`

If you want to have the same thick for top and bottom, use own background.

For example, you can use nine patch image.
Shadow generator: http://inloop.github.io/shadow4android/

Comment: Sorry, my question was poorly phrased. I meant that shadows around views close to the bottom is thicker than that around the views close to the top. I edited my question to reflect that. I was hoping to avoid using a background, but it sounds like I may have to if I want an even shadow. Thanks!