# Android: cardElevation to top

Tags: android, elevation, cardview

I use this code for elevation to leaner layout

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:cardCornerRadius="0dp"
        app:cardElevation="2dp"
        app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
        app:contentPadding="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="-3dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="-3dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="-3dp">
```

This code work for BOTTOM of layout, but i want elevation to top of layout

How i can ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [android:elevation only have shadow effects on the bottom side, how to make the shadow effects show on top side?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27741567/androidelevation-only-have-shadow-effects-on-the-bottom-side-how-to-make-the-s)

Comment: See & vote my answer below thanks !

Answer (score 0):

use `android:clipToPadding="false"`  in your parent layout

like below

```
<LinearLayout
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:clipToPadding="false"
                android:clipChildren="false"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp">

                <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                    app:cardElevation="5dp"
                    android:backgroundTint="@color/white"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="7dp">

                    <!--Your layout inside cardview-->
                                
                </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

            </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use **MaterialCardView** with this attributes :

```
<com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     app:cardCornerRadius="7dp"
     app:cardElevation="3dp"
     app:strokeColor="@color/color_light_grey"
     app:strokeWidth="1sp"
     />
```